# In spring boot project, When I click submit button, how can I solve Whitelabel Error Page Error,

Tags: spring-boot

When I click on submit button I got this error message

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Tue Jun 30 17:24:02 CST
>   2015 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No
>   message available

Here is my code.

```
 package com.tourpackage.controllers;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


    import com.tourpackage.model.TourPackage;
    import com.tourpackage.repository.TourPackageMongoRepository;
    import com.tourpackage.repository.VehicleTypeMongoRepository;

    @Controller
    public class TourPackageController {

        @Autowired
        TourPackageMongoRepository packageRepository;
        VehicleTypeMongoRepository vehicleTypeRepository;

        @RequestMapping("/tourpackage")
        public String tourpackage(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("packagelist", packageRepository.findAll());
            return "index";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/addNewTour")
        public String addNewTour(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("packagelist", packageRepository.findAll());
            return "tourpack";
        }


        @RequestMapping(value="/addPackage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addPackage(@ModelAttribute TourPackage tourpack) {
            packageRepository.save(tourpack);
            return "redirect:tourpackage";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot automatically registers the Basic ErrorController as a Spring Bean when you haven't specified an implementation for ErrorController.
so,
If you want to return customised content for path /error, refer following code:

@RestController
public class MyController implements ErrorController{

```
private static final String PATH = "/error";

@RequestMapping(value = PATH)
public String error() {
    return "Error handling";
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return PATH;
}
```

}

Else,
If you want to disable it, you can refer this post:
http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/disable-default-error-page/

Comment: Have you specified all the controller & service classes with annotation @ComponentScan in your main() class?